# How to describe data for a custom views filter in the my_module.schema.yml file?

Tags: views, 8, plugins

I encountered with a problem.

For creating a custom views filter in my own module I should also describe it in the my_module.schema.yml file.

Could you clarify me, how to do it?

For instance, there is a fragment of the views filter description from views.filter.schema.yml

```
views.filter.in_operator:
  type: views_filter
  label: 'IN operator'
  mapping:
    operator:
      type: string
      label: 'Operator'
    value:
      type: sequence
      label: 'Values'
      sequence:
        type: string
        label: 'Value'
    expose:
      type: mapping
      label: 'Expose'
      mapping:
        reduce:
          type: boolean
          label: 'Reduce'
    group_info:
      mapping:
        group_items:
          sequence:
            type: views.filter.group_item.in_operator
            label: 'Group item'
```

I would like to understand, what is this and where can I read the understandable documentation on how to create these descriptions for my own views filters?

Comment: Did you ever figure this out?  I would like to know too.